# Unity 5 after publish, android scene appears empty

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I'm working on a school project and we are building a game for Google Cardboard using Unity 5. I have all the drivers, SDK, and JDK files I need and I can play the game in editor and it will appear on my phone via the Unity Remote 4 app. It has terrible fps (less than 10, I'd guess) but that's not even my question.

I tried publishing the project and moving it to my phone to see if that would help with frame rate. Instead, I got a blue screen. Blue like an empty unity scene. I can still see the cardboard outline interface so I know that objects are still in the scene but I can't see anything.

Comment: Did you add your desired scenes in the Build settings > Scenes in build list?

Comment: Yes. It has been added to the build. I know the objects are in the scene because I still have the cardboard overlay on the camera but everything else is invisible.

Comment: are there any logcat errors logged?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can help you (without any further information) but you could try these options

- turn off Cardboard.SDK.nativeDistortionCorrection: to make Unity draw directly to the screen.
- Edit Cardboard.CreateStereoScreen() and change the settings.

ORIGINAL POST: [First answer by user "smd"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29633049/google-cardboard-for-unity-disables-aa-on-android-device?rq=1)

Comment: Turning off nativeDistortionCorrection gives me just a solid black screen on publish instead. Where do I edit the Cardboard.CreateStereoScreen() and how should I edit it?

Comment: I think that you already tested your game without the cardboard sdk (running it normally). If you didn't do that you should do that. If the error continues check your build settings. I can't give you any other solution without further information. Sorry for not being able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to File > **Build Settings**, select Android as the platform.
2. Click **Player Settings**, Under **Resolution and Presentation**, change default orientation to **Landscape Left**.

Comment: Tried that to no avail.

Comment: @RedXXVI Can you post a sceenshow of what it looks like in the editor and a screenshot of what it looks like in Android. This will really help determine what' going on

Comment: How it Looks In Unity: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3QTKyT_Y1P1blhiTnVaeFdaVlE                                                               How it Looks on Android after Publish https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3QTKyT_Y1P1SVpPaWxWRi1jakk

Comment: @RedXXVI I see. Can you also post picture of your **Game Hierarchy**? Also another picture of your **Build Settings**  Also what Unity version are you using. I know you have 5 but 5.?

Comment: @RedXXVI Delete/Remove the **FootstepsFromHell.unity** from the Build Settings and only leave the **FootstepsFromHell.unity**.Just select it and hit delete on your keyboard. Build it again and let me know what happens.

Comment: No change. The assignment was due today and the professor seems like they're going to give the class a break. We weren't the only group with problems. It would be nice to fix this, if for no other reason than someone else with this problem could find this thread and fix it. Before posting here, while looking for solutions, I found one other person on another website with the same problem on a Mac but they never solved it.

Comment: @RedXXVI There are still other things to try. File > Build Settings, select Android as the platform then change your Texture Compression from **PVRTC** to **Don't override**. Let me know if this works. I got one last solution.

Comment: Switching it from Don't Override to PVRTC was one of the things I did to try to fix the problem before turning to this forum so I know that won't work. At this point the project has a second unrelated problem where the library rebuilds itself every time I open it and it frequently freezes. I can barely get it back to the point where I can build to test how it works on my phone. Thanks for your help though. I appreciate you trying.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure split application binary is unselected under publishing settings

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with a blue screen on Android devices which sounds similar to this one. From what I found out it may happen that some Start() callbacks are not called correctly on Android in the startup scene. If nothing happens but the camera is active it only renders a blue background screen. This happens only very sporadically.

There are two things you can try:

1. Create an "empty" startup scene which only loads your actual scene.
2. Use not only Start() but also OnEnable() for backup.

If you are interested in the complete story have a look at my [blog entry](http://www.bellingo.de/blog/android-bluescreen/).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you hit "Add Open Scenes" in Build Settings such that all you scenes are added to the build. This was the solution for my case.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue for **Google cardboard** by these steps.

```
Edit -> Project settings -> Player -> Other settings -> Graphics APi
```

And remove **`Vulkan`** from the list by clicking `-` at the right bottom of the box.